# Multi-Hop Cycle in php

Tags: php, yahoo-weather-api

Can anyone tell what is the reason behind getting "HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Multi-Hop Cycle" error om using "file_get_contents" in PHP ?

Comment: I don't know the term "Multi-Hop Cycle" but maybe it's a loop of redirects?  Any decent HTTP client (which may include the implementation of `file_get_contents`) can detect this and exit the loop with an error, such as this.

Comment: file_get_contents(http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=24537643&amp;u=f); .. Error is thrown at this line..

Comment: This is what I'm seeing on my browser..Warning: file_get_contents(http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2442046&amp;u=f):
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Multi-Hop Cycle Detected in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Someproj/sometest.php on line 125